# current active directory search filter

Tags: c#, active-directory

Here's my current Active Directory search filter:

```
        deSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user))";
```

how do I modify it to find a particular user/users in active directory? For example, how do I search for

```
first names that begin with San*?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no expert but try

```
(&(objectClass=user)(givenName=San*))
```